# How to know who is Google ADS account with ad client number?

Tags: wordpress, ads, adsense

how are you?

I'm having a little problem with my website, a few weeks ago i realized that i had google ads in my wordpress website, i checked in the widgets and i could delete them from there, but yesterday they had been added again but now in the code of my footer and header.

I need to know who is the person adding the ads, is there any way to know it having the client number?

the number is: 
data-ad-client="ca-pub-0989337553679314"

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a self-hosted Wordpress install, or are you using a site through Wordpress.com? The ads are simply appearing on your site without your permission? You may want to change your password in case you've been hacked.

Comment: I could solve the problem. I made a reverse search using the ad cliente number, and i realized that a programmer who had been working in the website added that ads. In the reverse search there where some website that he manage.